# Is there an input field for unique values for Infopath Forms within SharePoint? If not, how to create one?

Tags: infopath, form, forms-services, forms-library

Goal: I am attempting to create an Intake Form on Infopath and publish it to an already existing SharePoint list as shown below:

[image: Intake Form]

As you can see, the first field is `ID#`, which I left the right row blank for now because I am trying to find an input type to pair it up with that will auto increment and create a unique `ID#` so each form submitted is unique.

As an example, `Date of Request` I set to `Date Picker` input. `Region` is a `Drop-Down List` that I populated with my own custom values. I want the `ID#` to be an input that generates a unique and auto incremented value for all my forms.

Here are the list of inputs/objects/containers:

[image: List of Options]

I am trying to find one that suits my needs for a unique value to be generated to be the form's ID number.

Is there one I can choose? If not, can someone advise on how to create one, using one of these existing options?